# PHP MVC passing form values to controller and model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to send POST values to the controller and then pass it to the model in PHP but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

This part of the controller is to see if the user requests for a view like `?action=game`. This works.

But I'm trying to modify it to allow `$_POST` to be sent to it and then to the model.

```
function __construct()
{
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']!="" )
     {
         $url_view = str_replace("action/","",$_GET['action']);
         if(file_exists("views/" . $url_view . ".php" ))
         {
                $viewname = $url_view;
                $this->get_view($viewname . ".php");
          }
          else
          {
               $this->get_view('error.php');
          }
     } 
     else 
     {
         $this->get_view('home.php');
     }  
}
```

Here's what I got. In the registration form page, the action of the form is `?process=register` but it doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['process']) == 'register)
{
    $this->get_view('register.php')
}
```

Get_view function determines what model to bind with the view

```
function get_view($view_name)
{
    $method_name = str_replace(".php","",$view_name);
    if(method_exists($this->model,$method_name))
    {
       $data = $this->model->$method_name();
    } else {
      $data = $this->model->no_model();
    }
      $this->load->view($view_name,$data);
}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing singlequote in if(isset($_POST['process']) == 'register)

Answer (score 4):

Since the action of your form is `?process=register`, then `process` is still in the `$_GET` superglobal.  What you can do to make it use post is add a hidden input field containing process.

With this:

```
<form method="post" action="script.php?process=register">
```

The form is POST'ed to `script.php?process=register` so you have `$_GET['process']`, **not** `$_POST['process']`.

Try this instead:

```
<form method="post" action="script.php">
<input type="hidden" name="process" action="register" />
```

To have `$_POST['process']`.  Alternatively, you could keep the "process" in the GET and switch your if statement to check `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks. But i can't seem to get it working. when i post to the controller in the registerform it just goes to a blank page even when i put in a view name to test

Comment: Blank page means you have a fatal error in your script, most likely it is the missing `'` others mentioned.  If you turn the PHP setting `display_errors` on you can see the actual errors.